# How do I bin currency values that has currency symbol in the beginning using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binning

I have currency values, for example, `$569000` in my dataset and I want to bin them as `$500000-600000` with the currency symbol in the front. However, because of the currency symbol, the values are not an integer or any number types. Do I need to remove the $ symbol, bin the values, and then add it back?

Comment: If you want to treat these values as numbers (which it seems you do), then yes, remove the `$` and convert to a number. Later, when you need to output/present, you can add the `$` as part of converting to a string.

Comment: Thank you! I am okay with not converting it as long as they are binned correctly. Is there any other way to do it in that case? I am just exploring different options for me to consider.

Comment: Just Write a substring to remove the first charcter and check it with if else (if substr()...>500000 and < 60000) then "$50000-60000" else...

Comment: Be careful if these numbers include decimals e.g. "$123.45".